# Trouble with ASC

Tags: vb.net

Hey I wanted to make it so that whenever I click button if textbox1  contains anything other than a number it will show me in the message box "You can only enter numbers" 
I am having trouble figuring out how to properly use the Asc function

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If Asc(TextBox1.Text) < 48 Or Asc(TextBox1.Text) > 57 Then
        TextBox1.Text = True
        MessageBox.Show("You can only enter numbers")

    End If
```

Comment: Hey please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: check the content of e.KeyCode, not the entire Text into the textBox

Comment: Use `IsNumeric` instead of `Asc`.

Comment: Instead of TextBox, use NumericUpDown. If you don't want decimals, set DecimalPlaces = 0. If you want to limit range, use Maximum and Minimum.

Comment: If you check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx) it says " If String is a String expression, only the first character of the string is used for input". So your code only checks the first character of the string.

Comment: See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you *must* use a TextBox, there's no need for the `Asc` function. Use Integer/Double.TryParse

```
' if you want to accept doubles
Dim numberDouble As Double
If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, numberDouble) Then
    TextBox1.Text = True
    MessageBox.Show("You can only enter doubles")
End If

' if you want to accept integers
Dim numberInteger As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, numberInteger) Then
    TextBox1.Text = True
    MessageBox.Show("You can only enter integers")
End If
```

Better yet, use a NumericUpDown, which has all the validation built in.

```
Dim numberDecimal As Decimal = NumericUpDown1.Value
Dim numberDouble = Convert.ToDouble(NumericUpDown1.Value)
Dim numberInteger = Convert.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value)
```

Just set NumericUpDown.Maximum and NumericUpDown.Minumum, and NumericUpDown.DecimalPlaces before it's used (i.e. in the designer) and all the validation is taken care of.